# How to access media files in django

Tags: python, django, templates

In my settings I have

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

my uploaded files are saved in media folder..

In my template now I want to access these files

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{file.my_file}}" width="100" height="100" /></a>
```

When I do this its not showing the images or file.How can I get the file.. What should I use ?

Comment: {{file.my_files}} give the image from context.  doing <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}} images/pic.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></a> not giving the image so

Comment: you should  look at this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: If you inspect the image path that is being generated in your browser's console, what does it say?

Comment: What does your `urls.py` look like? Make sure you have the following set `if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
`

Answer (score 1):

what i have set in settings.py:
`MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/paulius/django-paulius/epc/static/'`

there i have several folders for my static files. one of them is for uploaded files.
in my template i would write:
`<p><a href="/static/assets/{{patient.thumbnail}}">FILE</a></p>`

this one works. i am using it right now. try checking the url to your files, maybe you misprinted something